# New dual monitor setup on debian xfce

Tags: multiple-monitors, debian, xfce

I'm sure this belongs in another stack site, but I don't know which one.

Either way, I've been using Arch with dual monitors for a while, eventually, a system upgrade somehow ruined my video drivers, and I was stuck with only one monitor.  I dealt with that for a while, but then it stopped booting.  I love Arch but don't have the time.

I switched to Debian with Xfce, and can't seem to get the second monitor recognized, can someone point me to the right stack, or just give some help?

```
parris@link:/etc/X11$ lspci
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a1)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a2)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a2)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1)
00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2)
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2)
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:06.0 Communication controller: LSI Corporation Lucent V.92 Data/Fax Modem
01:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar PRO [Radeon HD 5450/6350]
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8039 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
parris@link:/etc/X11$
```

.

```
parris@link:/etc/X11$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 375mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

. After $ X -configure
Not sure why it added 80 zillion monitors...

```
parris@link:/etc/X11$ cat /etc/X11/
app-defaults/            X                        Xreset                   Xsession.d/              
default-display-manager  xinit/                   Xreset.d/                Xsession.options         
fonts/                   xkb/                     Xresources/              XvMCConfig               
rgb.txt                  xorg.conf.new            Xsession                 Xwrapper.config          
parris@link:/etc/X11$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.new 
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen      3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    Screen      4  "Screen4" RightOf "Screen3"
    Screen      5  "Screen5" RightOf "Screen4"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor2"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor3"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor4"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor5"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:0:13:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac6Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Dac8Bit"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BusType"               # [<str>]
        #Option     "CPPIOMode"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CPusecTimeout"         # <i>
        #Option     "AGPMode"               # <i>
        #Option     "AGPFastWrite"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AGPSize"               # <i>
        #Option     "GARTSize"              # <i>
        #Option     "RingSize"              # <i>
        #Option     "BufferSize"            # <i>
        #Option     "EnableDepthMoves"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EnablePageFlip"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoBackBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DMAForXv"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FBTexPercent"          # <i>
        #Option     "DepthBits"             # <i>
        #Option     "PCIAPERSize"           # <i>
        #Option     "AccelDFS"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "IgnoreEDID"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # [<str>]
        #Option     "DisplayPriority"       # [<str>]
        #Option     "PanelSize"             # [<str>]
        #Option     "ForceMinDotClock"      # <freq>
        #Option     "ColorTiling"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreCrystal"    # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreTunerPort"  # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreCompositePort"  # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreSVideoPort"     # <i>
        #Option     "TunerType"             # <i>
        #Option     "RageTheatreMicrocPath"     # <str>
        #Option     "RageTheatreMicrocType"     # <str>
        #Option     "ScalerWidth"           # <i>
        #Option     "RenderAccel"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SubPixelOrder"         # [<str>]
        #Option     "ClockGating"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VGAAccess"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReverseDDC"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LVDSProbePLL"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ConnectorTable"        # <str>
        #Option     "DefaultConnectorTable"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultTMDSPLL"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TVDACLoadDetect"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ForceTVOut"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TVStandard"            # <str>
        #Option     "IgnoreLidStatus"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultTVDACAdj"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Int10"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "EXAVSync"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ATOMTVOut"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "R4xxATOM"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ForceLowPowerMode"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DynamicPM"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NewPLL"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card2"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:13:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card3"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card4"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:13:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card5"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Card2"
    Monitor    "Monitor2"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen3"
    Device     "Card3"
    Monitor    "Monitor3"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen4"
    Device     "Card4"
    Monitor    "Monitor4"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen5"
    Device     "Card5"
    Monitor    "Monitor5"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I managed to have this working on Arch, after a weekend of working, but was hoping Debian would be a little bit easier on me.

I can supply any more output.  When I last loaded Arch, the CLI showed two monitors, but Xfce did not.

Thanks a million!  I was about 1 day from delivering a friend a new simple business website (friend price -- free :)), he would also appreciate.

If someone tells me that Gnome will magically solve everything, I can reinstall, however I've grown to love xfce.

thanks!

Edit: I think the disconnect is that lspci sees the extra video card, while xandr doesn't...

Edit: lspci -v

```
parris@link:/etc/X11$ sudo lspci -v
[sudo] password for parris: 
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [44] HyperTransport: Slave or Primary Interface
    Capabilities: [dc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed-

00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0

00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, IRQ 5
    I/O ports at fc00 [size=64]
    I/O ports at 1c00 [size=64]
    I/O ports at f400 [size=64]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: nForce2_smbus

00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel

00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fe02f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at fe02e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [44] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=0098
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 0000b000-0000bfff
    Memory behind bridge: fdf00000-fdffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: fd900000-fd9fffff
    Capabilities: [b8] Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device cb84
    Capabilities: [8c] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed-

00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device a88d
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fe028000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [6c] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 IDE (rev a2) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0
    [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
    [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
    [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pata_amd

00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at 09f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0bf0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 0970 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0b70 [size=4]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=16]
    Memory at fe02d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [cc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv

00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [Master SecO PriO])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at 09e0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0be0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 0960 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0b60 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c800 [size=16]
    Memory at fe02c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [cc] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed+
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv

00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000a000-0000afff
    Memory behind bridge: fde00000-fdefffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000efffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0000
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [60] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed-
    Capabilities: [80] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00009000-00009fff
    Memory behind bridge: fdd00000-fddfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fdc00000-00000000fdcfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0000
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [60] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed-
    Capabilities: [80] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00008000-00008fff
    Memory behind bridge: fdb00000-fdbfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fda00000-00000000fdafffff
    Capabilities: [40] Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0000
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [60] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable- Fixed-
    Capabilities: [80] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 2601
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at fb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at c0000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [80] HyperTransport: Host or Secondary Interface

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: [f0] Secure device <?>
    Kernel driver in use: k8temp

01:06.0 Communication controller: LSI Corporation Lucent V.92 Data/Fax Modem
    Subsystem: LSI Corporation Device 0621
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at bc00 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3

01:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 8024
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at fdfff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Memory at fdff8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar PRO [Radeon HD 5450/6350] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Device e164
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256M]
    Memory at fdec0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    I/O ports at ac00 [disabled] [size=256]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fde00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting

02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Device aa68
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at fdefc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8039 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems Device 8039
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at fddfc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at 9c00 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [5c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
```

Still Editing:
apt-get install for all say up to date:
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau

ex:

```
root@link:/etc/X11# apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-ati is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-video-ati set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Note, I already posted this on [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355422/new-dual-monitor-setup-on-debian-xfce?noredirect=1#comment25184455_17355422)

Answer (score 3):

I'm personnaly using the opensource nvidia driver with xrandr to handle my dual-screen.

THe only configuration is in my .xinitrc :

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 -s 3840x1080
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DVI-0 --left-of DVI-1
```

You will probably have some modification to make it fit with your setup.

**EDIT**

In your home directory you have a **.xinitrc** file. This file is read by the *startx* command or connection manager like slim.

I don't know what connection manager you are using, but assuming you are using the *startx* command you have to edit your **.xinitrc** file and add the previous lines before you start xfce4.

Example of .xinitrc file I have on a archlinux box running xfce4 :

```
# ~/.xinitrc
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --output DVI-0 -s 3840x1080
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DVI-0 --left-of DVI-1

exec startxfce4
```

Comment: I copied this to my home directory, is that correct?